# Load html <img> with jwt-token included

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

Im using reactjs in a project. I have this "image server" (asp net core web api with an authorize-attribute) so it requires a jwt-token.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
[HttpGet("{galleryShortName}/{fileName}")]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetImage(string galleryShortName, string fileName) {...}
```

Is there any way I can send my access token with calls from server in my -tags?

[This article](https://js.plainenglish.io/loading-images-with-authorization-8aab33663ba6) seems to do this with angular pipes. I cant say that I understand 100% of the article, I dont speak Angular, but is there any way to sneak in a token in the requests.

Another alternative would be have placeholder imgs, and to load the imagedata with fetch(using auth header), but how do I put them in the placeholders?

Any other suggestions are welcome how to do this are welcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is essentially suggesting that you perform the http request to fetch the image using a JavaScript XHR request and then convert the image into base64 so that you can use that as the src of the img tag.

The article you linked is for Angular.js which is different from React.js. If you want to do the method described in the article, here is a pure JS solution for it. I would then wrap this inside of a custom image component.

```js
// This function is asynchronous since it returns a promise
// It converts a binary blob into a base64 string representation
function blobToBase64(blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
    });
}

function fetchImageAsBase64(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const jwt = "pretend this is a jwt";

        // Make a headers object that we can add to the request
        const headers = new Headers({
            authorization: "Bearer " + jwt,
        });

        // Make the request and wait for the response
        window
            .fetch(url, { headers })
            .then((response) => response.blob())
            .then((blob) => blobToBase64(blob))
            .then((base64) => resolve(base64));
    });
}

// This is our custom image component that puts this together
class SecureImage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            imageSrc: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetchImageAsBase64(this.props.src).then((base64String) => {
            this.setState({
                imageSrc: base64String,
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.imageSrc) {
            // If you want you can return a loading component here
        }

        return <img src={this.state.imageSrc} alt={this.props.alt} width={200} />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SecureImage src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="placeholder" />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! When you say it is not worth it, what to you mean? is it because its to messy or any performance issue with this. I have considered the cookie-route as well, but  Im a bit worried about security, for example (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180357/store-auth-token-in-cookie-or-header)...but maybe its possible to use cookie-handling with SameSite=true

Comment: @Cowborg Actually nevermind, the hit to performance will likely be negligible. I wouldn't worry too much about it.